# jQuery slide show - Images not show in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I am using [Camera slideshow](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/) and everything is OK in Chrome and Internet Explorer but in Firefox the Images do not show

How can I change this code so the images show?

HTML :

```
<div class="camera_wrap pattern_4 camera_emboss" id="camera_wrap_4">
                    <div data-src="Content/Images/demo/slide1.jpg">
                        <div class="camera_caption fadeFromTop">
                            <h1>MultiPurpose Responsive Template</h1>
                            <span>Professional & modern website template created for you and your business prosperity. Build a top-notch business website in no time! </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-src="Content/Images/demo/slide2.jpg">
                        <div class="camera_caption fadeFromRight">
                            <h1>Professional Design & Elegant Code</h1>
                            <span>Beautiful behind the scenes too! Biscaya Template comes with top notch customer support to help you get your business online fast. </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS :

```
/**************************
*
*   GENERAL
*
**************************/
.camera_wrap a, .camera_wrap img, 
.camera_wrap ol, .camera_wrap ul, .camera_wrap li,
.camera_wrap table, .camera_wrap tbody, .camera_wrap tfoot, .camera_wrap thead, .camera_wrap tr, .camera_wrap th, .camera_wrap td
.camera_thumbs_wrap a, .camera_thumbs_wrap img, 
.camera_thumbs_wrap ol, .camera_thumbs_wrap ul, .camera_thumbs_wrap li,
.camera_thumbs_wrap table, .camera_thumbs_wrap tbody, .camera_thumbs_wrap tfoot, .camera_thumbs_wrap thead, .camera_thumbs_wrap tr, .camera_thumbs_wrap th, .camera_thumbs_wrap td {
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    list-style: none
}
.camera_wrap {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
.camera_wrap img {
    max-width: none!important;
}
.camera_fakehover {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}
.camera_wrap {
    width: 100%;
}
.camera_src {
    display: none;
}
.cameraCont, .cameraContents {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.cameraSlide {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.cameraContent {
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.camera_target {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: left;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
.camera_overlayer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
.camera_target_content {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.camera_target_content .camera_link {
    background: url(Images/blank.gif);
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.camera_loader {
    background: #fff url(Images/camera-loader.gif) no-repeat center;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) url(Images/camera-loader.gif) no-repeat center;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
    -moz-border-radius: 18px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    height: 36px;
    left: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -18px 0 0 -18px;
    top: 50%;
    width: 36px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.camera_bar {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
.camera_thumbs_wrap.camera_left .camera_bar, .camera_thumbs_wrap.camera_right .camera_bar {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
}
.camera_thumbs_wrap.camera_bottom .camera_bar, .camera_thumbs_wrap.camera_top .camera_bar {
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.camera_nav_cont {
    height: 65px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 9px;
    top: 15px;
    width: 120px;
    z-index: 4;
}
.camera_caption {
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.camera_caption > div {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.camerarelative {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.imgFake {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.camera_prevThumbs {
    bottom: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 30px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.camera_prevThumbs div {
    background: url(Images/camera_skins.png) no-repeat -160px 0;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 30px;
}
.camera_nextThumbs {
    bottom: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 4px;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 30px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.camera_nextThumbs div {
    background: url(Images/camera_skins.png) no-repeat -190px 0;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 30px;
}
.camera_command_wrap .hideNav {
    display: none;
}
.camera_command_wrap {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    right:0;
    z-index: 4;
}
.camera_wrap .camera_pag .camera_pag_ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
.camera_wrap .camera_pag .camera_pag_ul li {
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 20px 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 16px;
}
.camera_commands_emboss .camera_pag .camera_pag_ul li {
    -moz-box-shadow:
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1),
        inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1),
        inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow:
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1),
        inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.camera_wrap .camera_pag .camera_pag_ul li > span {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 8px;
    left: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    width: 8px;
}
.camera_commands_emboss .camera_pag .camera_pag_ul li:hover > span {
    -moz-box-shadow:
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1),
        inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1),
        inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow:
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1),
        inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.camera_wrap .camera_pag .camera_pag_ul li.cameracurrent > span {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
}
.camera_pag_ul li img {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.camera_pag_ul .thumb_arrow {
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -4px;
    position: absolute;
}
.camera_prev, .camera_next, .camera_commands {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.camera_prev {
    left: 0;
}
.camera_prev > span {
    background: url(Images/camera_skins.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
.camera_next {
    right: 0;
}
.camera_next > span {
    background: url(Images/camera_skins.png) no-repeat -40px 0;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
.camera_commands {
    right: 41px;
}
.camera_commands > .camera_play {
    background: url(Images/camera_skins.png) no-repeat -80px 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
.camera_commands > .camera_stop {
    background: url(Images/camera_skins.png) no-repeat -120px 0;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
.camera_wrap .camera_pag .camera_pag_ul li {
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 20px 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 16px;
}
.camera_thumbs_cont {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.camera_commands_emboss .camera_thumbs_cont {
    -moz-box-shadow:
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1),
        inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1),
        inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow:
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1),
        inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.camera_thumbs_cont > div {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.camera_thumbs_cont ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px 4px 8px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.camera_thumbs_cont ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 4px;
}
.camera_thumbs_cont ul li > img {
    border: 1px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 5px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.camera_clear {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.showIt {
    display: none;
}
.camera_clear {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px 0 25px;
    position: relative;
}
/**************************
*
*   COLORS & SKINS
*
**************************/
/*BROWN SKIN*/
.camera_brown_skin .camera_prevThumbs div {
    background-position: -160px -320px;
}
.camera_brown_skin .camera_nextThumbs div {
    background-position: -190px -320px;
}
.camera_brown_skin .camera_prev > span {
    background-position: 0 -320px;
}
.camera_brown_skin .camera_next > span {
    background-position: -40px -320px;
}
.camera_brown_skin .camera_commands > .camera_play {
    background-position: -80px -320px;
}
.camera_brown_skin .camera_commands > .camera_stop {
    background-position: -120px -320px;
}







.cameraContents .camera_caption h1 {
background: #222;
display: block;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 21px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 1.4;
padding: 10px;

}

.cameraContents .camera_caption span {
background: #e7402f;
color: #fff;
display: block;
line-height: 24px;
padding: 17px 20px 15px 20px;
font-size: 14px;
}

.cameraContents .camera_caption div {
background: none;
margin-top:-70%;
}
.camera_caption{
left: 5%;
width:45%;
display:inline;
}
```

JS :

```
$(function () {
            $('#camera_wrap_4').camera({
                height: 'auto',
                loader: 'bar',
                pagination: false,
                thumbnails: false,
                hover: false,
                opacityOnGrid: false
            });
        });
```

Comment: The images in that link show up fine in firefox!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using firebug to debug any given css within js. Play with current image styles.